# Stream API allMatch() with mulitple nullable nested objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm working on a request validation feature where I need to check if a certain string value is present in a property that is contained in an object, which is contained as a value of a map entry, that map is a part of an object and finally my request body contains a set of those objects.

To try and make it clearer I will recreate my situation using only parts of code that are important.

Lets say my `ClassA` is received in request body, it has following properties:

```
@Nullable
Set<ClassB> mySet = null;
```

Now, we have `ClassB` that has a certain wrapper object of type `ClassC`:

```
@Nullable 
ClassC classC;
```

That wrapper class `ClassC` contains a map:

```
@Nullable
Map<String, ClassD> classDMap = new HashMap<>;
```

Finally, `ClassD` contains the property that needs to be checked if it contains a certain value:

```
@Nullable
String propertyForValidation;
```

At the moment I went with code that looks like this:

```
public boolean isValid(ClassA body) {
  return body.getMySet().stream()
                        .allMatch(x -> x.getClassC().getClassDMap().values().stream()
                        .allMatch(y -> y.getPropertyForValidation.equals("someValue"));
}
```

Current problem with my code is that it does not work as expected when some objects that I've described above are null since I'm getting a lot of `NullPointerException`s. I suppose this can be resolved with a lot ifs and null checks, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it using Stream API?

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you could use something like `Optional.of(x).map(ClassB::getClassC).map(ClassC::getClassDMap).map(Map::getValues).stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using a single `Stream`.
It is a bit repetitive but should comply with your expected results.

Note the usage of:

- `Objects#nonNull` to check the nullity of an object using a method reference
- The way the literal `String` is used first with `equals` to avoid the last `NullPointerException` possible

---

```
public boolean isValid(ClassA body) {
    return ofNullable(body.getMySet())
               .orElse(emptySet())
               .stream()
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .map(ClassB::getClassC)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .map(ClassC::getClassDMap)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream())
               .allMatch(y -> "someValue".equals(y.getPropertyForValidation()));
}
```

Comment: Your approach works, I've just added ofNullable(body.getMySet()).orElse(emptySet()) since it was failing if MySet was null. You can edit your answer for future uses.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try making use of [Stream.filter()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-filter-java-examples/). Something like `Stream.filter(x -> x!=null)` should work instead of (and be more elegant than) `if` statements.

In your case it would be necessary before every one of your object or field (that is nullable) getters I'm afraid. But that's the most streamish' way I'd go for.

You can also use it in conjuction with the isEmpty() method for cases of empty maps.

An alternative would be to add `if` statements *within* your getter functions. That would allow you to keep the exact stream you wrote already.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've accepted Yassin's approach though.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the comment of @Turing85, I tried to work this out with `Optional`s. I would *not* recommend this method but figured it could be educational to share here!

The effect of each `orElse(Boolean.TRUE)` is to return true when the respective component is missing/set is empty (if a missing component should fail validation, change this to `Boolean.FALSE`). If we can assume that no `null` values are ever set on the `Map` of `ClassD`, then `Stream::allMatch` can work directly on `ClassD` instead of `Optional<ClassD>`. Luckily, the final `String::equals` comparison provides one `null` check for free against the value returned by `ClassD::getPropertyForValidation`.

```java
public boolean isValid(ClassA body) {
   return Optional.ofNullable(body)
           .flatMap(a -> Optional.ofNullable(a.getMySet()))
           .map(Set::stream)
           .map(streamB -> streamB
                   .map(b -> Optional.ofNullable(b.getClassC()))
                   .map(opC -> opC.flatMap(c -> Optional.ofNullable(c.getClassDMap())))
                   .map(opMapD -> opMapD
                           .map(map -> map.values().stream()
                                   .map(d -> Optional.ofNullable(d))
                                   .allMatch(opD -> opD
                                           .map(d -> "someValue".equals(d.getPropertyForValidation()))
                                           .orElse(Boolean.TRUE)))
                           .orElse(Boolean.TRUE))
                   .reduce((acc, item) -> acc && item)
                   .orElse(Boolean.TRUE))
           .orElse(Boolean.TRUE);
}
```